# get list of student with attendance min15days in a month and come for continuous 4 months in a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need a query to get the list of students attended there class for atleast 15 days in a month for continuous 4 months.

table maybe like

```
studentid   monthyear   attendance
1            Apr2018      16
1            May2018      23
1            Jun2018      18
1            Jul2018      16
1            Aug2018      25
2            Apr2018      2
2            May2018      15
```

and so on...

[Db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jkGXxAKyeyzZE4SdokGVLB/2)

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: why is the monthyear column like that, why isn't it numeric?

Comment: What u have tried?

Comment: I am using sql server 2012. I want to show month as mmmyyyy format

Comment: I have written a procedure where I am reading records line by line and updating it in a cursor with new field monthcount. Then I am doing query on that cursor. Its wroking... but looking for some better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select @rn := 0;
select studentid from (
  select studentid, month(dt) - (@rn := @rn + 1) grp from (
    select * ,
           str_to_date(concat('01 ', insert(monthyear, 4, 0, ' ')), '%d %M %Y') dt
    from tbl
    where attendance >= 15 --only those records, where attenadnce is at least 15
  ) a where year(dt) = 2018 --particular year
  order by studentid,dt
) a group by studentid,grp having count(*) >= 4
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jkGXxAKyeyzZE4SdokGVLB/1) - I exapnded your data with some more cases :)

The idea is simple - if student has attended for some consecutive months, consecutive months would increment by one, just like row number, so I used difference between months and row numbers - for consecutive months, the difference should be constant, so it's enought to group by that difference and take those groups, where count is >= 4 :)

**UPDATE**

For SQL Server:

```
select studentid from (
  select studentid, month(dt) - row_number() over (order by studentid, dt) grp from (
    select * ,
           cast(concat('01 ', stuff(monthyear, 4, 0, ' ')) as date) dt
    from tbl
    where attendance >= 15 --only those records, where attenadnce is at least 15
  ) a where year(dt) = 2018 --particular year
) a group by studentid, grp having count(*) >= 4
```

[SQL Server demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/474c0a/12)

Comment: i hope it is in mysql. I am using SSMS

Comment: @Santosh First is for MySQL, second is for SQL Server. And I don't understand, why do you want query for MySQL, when you are using SQL Server?

Comment: Will it also work for financial year like April 2018 to March 2019?

Comment: @Santosh No, you would need to modify it little bit.

Comment: I changed "where year(dt) = 2018" to "where dt between '04/01/2018' and '03/31/2019'

Comment: @Santosh Well, in one case, when the months are 11, 12, 1, 2 - they are consecutive, but this query won't see it as consecutive. You need to further change this query, but I think you'll handle it easily :)

Comment: Changed month(dt) to month(dt)+((year(dt)-year('04/01/2018'))*12)

Comment: @Santosh Brilliant ;) I thought of exactly the same :) But you could use simplier `month(dt)+((year(dt)-2018)*12)` and you could use any number isntead of 2018 :) It's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a simple selft join that would catch the difference of months would suffice
In this case, a conversion of the column monthyear is required in the join command itself

The query, without the conversion :

```
SELECT t1.studentid, count(*) as cnt
FROM
table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.studentid = t2.studentid AND
t2.attendance >= 15
AND t1.monthyear BETWEEN t2.monthyear AND (t2.monthyear - 3)
WHERE 
t1.attendance >= 15
GROUP BY
studentid
HAVING
count(*)  >=4
```

The conversion is as follows:

```
STR_TO_DATE(
CONCAT(SUBSTR(t1.monthyear,1, LENGTH(t1.monthyear) - 4),' ', RIGHT(t1.monthyear, 4), %M %Y)
```

so the query should be:

```
SELECT t1.studentid, count(*) as cnt
    FROM
    table t1
    INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.studentid = t2.studentid AND
    t2.attendance >= 15
    AND STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(SUBSTR(t1.monthyear,1, LENGTH(t1.monthyear) - 4),' ', RIGHT(t1.monthyear, 4), %M %Y) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(SUBSTR(t2.monthyear,1, LENGTH(t2.monthyear) - 4),' ', RIGHT(t2.monthyear, 4), %M %Y) AND DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(SUBSTR(t2.monthyear,1, LENGTH(t2.monthyear) - 4),' ', RIGHT(t2.monthyear, 4), %M %Y), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
    WHERE 
    t1.attendance >= 15
    GROUP BY
    studentid
    HAVING
    count(*)  >=4
```

Comment: strange as it is defined in the select. I'll do a minor fix

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest method:

```
select distinct studentid
from (select t.*, cast(monthyear as date) as my,
             lag(cast(monthyear as date), 3) over (partition by studentid order by cast(monthyear as date)) as prev_my
      from tbl t
      where attendance >= 15
     ) t
where prev_my = dateadd(month, -3, my);
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc962a16e9e02394d4a075a92624841b).

The logic is pretty simple:

- Only consider rows that satisfy the attendance criterion.
- Use `LAG()` to look at the 3rd record in past.
- If all months meet the attendance criterion, then this will be exactly 3 months before.

The `select distinct` is because you want students, not the specific periods.